# Combinatoric question - arrange balls in cells [Probability]

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

We want to arrange $10$ (different) balls in $4$ cells, what is the chance that $5$ will be entered to cell number $1$, and the rest of them will enter an even cell ($2$ or $4$)?

My attempt:

Note that we have a symmetric space, in which we have $4^{10}$ options to arrange the balls.

Let us choose $5$ balls to enter cell $1$ - $\binom{10}{5}$.

Then we have to arrange the next $5$ balls in an even cell, so each one of them has $2$ options, to enter cell number $2$ or cell number $4$, which is: $\binom{5}{5} \cdot 2^5$.

So in total we have: $$\frac{\binom{10}{5} + \binom{5}{5} \cdot 2^5}{4^{10}}=0.027 ~\% $$

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: @Carl Can you explain why please?

Comment: @Carl Why is the probability different in this case?

Comment: I think all your reasoning is correct, but in the calculation you should not add but multiply. You'll then get the same result as in Snoop's answer.

Comment: Good point! @JaapScherphuis

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you, can you explain why do I need to multiply and not add?

Comment: It's the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). Each arrangement combines any particular choice for the first five balls with the choices for the last 5 balls. It is multiplied for the same reason that you are multiplying the five factors of 2 for those last 5 balls. For each particular arrangement all those choices have to be combined together. The [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) is used when things are not simultaneous, e.g. when you have arrangement of two different types, that are one thing or the other, not a combination of both.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you so much for your answer! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability for a ball to end up in any of the $4$ bins is uniform $(=0.25)$ so
$$P=\sum_{k=0}^5\underbrace{\frac{10!}{5!(5-k)!0!k!}(0.25)^{10}}_{\textrm{Probability of 5 balls in B1, 5-k in B2, 0 in B3, k in B4}}$$
so
$$\frac{10!\cdot 0.25^{10}\cdot 2}{5!}\bigg(\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{3!2!}\bigg)\approx 0.0077$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do not know this formula.. I would like to prove it combinatoric if possible.

Answer (score 0):

We might view this problem as an example of the Multinomial Distribution. There are $10$ independent trials, and in each trial either (1) a ball lands in bin $1$, with probability $1/4$; (2) a ball lands in bin $2$ or bin $4$, with probability $2/4$; or (3) a ball lands in bin $3$, with probability $1/4$.  Then the probability of the outcome $(5,5,0)$ is
$$\binom{10}{5 \quad 5 \quad 0} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^5 \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)^5 = \frac{10!}{5! 5! 0!} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^5 \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)^5 = 0.00769043$$